# unable to change source IP with winsock

Tags: c++, winsock

My problem is that I can't change the source IP with Winsock no matter which way I set the source. From the output, I can see that srcIP is changed every loop but the packet captured by wireshark is always my host's IP(192.168.137.1). What might be the problem? Is it because I use the local socket?(Environment: Windows 10)

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<WinSock2.h>
#include<Ws2tcpip.h>
#include<iostream>
#include<tchar.h>
#include<string>
#define IN_PORT 8888
#define OUT_PORT 50
#define BUFLEN 512  //Max length of buffer
#pragma comment(lib,"ws2_32.lib") //Winsock Library
// compile g++ flood.cpp -lwsock32 -lstdc++ -o flood.exe
using namespace std;
int main(){
    SOCKET s;
    struct sockaddr_in src,dst;
    WSADATA wsa;
    const char* dstIP = "192.168.137.209";
    const char* srcIP = "192.168.137.2";//set up srcIP
    //Initialise winsock
    WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2),&wsa);
    
    const char* pkt = "This is a Probe";
    // setup src
    memset(&src, 0, sizeof(src));
    src.sin_family = AF_INET;
    src.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(srcIP);
    src.sin_port = htons(IN_PORT);
    // setup dst
    memset(&dst, 0, sizeof(dst));
    dst.sin_family = AF_INET;
    dst.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(dstIP);
    dst.sin_port = htons(OUT_PORT);
    //create socket
    s=socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);
    //Bind
    bind(s ,(struct sockaddr *)&src , sizeof(src));
    // send packet
    sendto(s, pkt, strlen(pkt), 0, (struct sockaddr*) &dst, sizeof(dst));
    // close socket and quit
    }
    closesocket(s);
    WSACleanup();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You [cannot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/tcp-ip-raw-sockets-2?redirectedfrom=MSDN#limitations-on-raw-sockets) send any source IP on Windows even with raw sockets: `The IP source address for any outgoing UDP datagram must exist on a network interface or the datagram is dropped. This change was made to limit the ability of malicious code to create distributed denial-of-service attacks`

Comment: @dewaffled I'm using windows 10. I guess should be fine

Comment: @anonymousbear You can't `bind()` a socket to an IP that doesn't belong to the local host. You say that the local host's IP is `192.168.137.1`, but does that same host also have IP `192.168.137.2` installed as well? If not, then `bind()` will fail, which you are not checking for (in fact, you are not doing any error handling at all).